# Is this a mistake in a Stanford Encyclopedia article on Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, soft-question

In the SEP's article dealing with Quantum Mechanics , I read this ( *Section 2.1, " Vectors and Vector Spaces"*) https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm/:

> $|A⟩$ and $|B⟩$ are mutually perpendicular, or orthogonal, if, and
> only if, $⟨A∣B⟩$.

But, as far as I understand, $\langle A|B\rangle$ has previously been defined as a number ( i.e. inner product), not a proposition.

So it seems to me that one should have : " if and only if $\langle A|B\rangle$ equals ... "

Do I miss something or does the article contain a typo?

Comment: It seems that they forgot to put $=0$, yes.

Comment: Thanks for answering  @Jacob.